# How to check if the number of steps are divisible by a multiplier of 100

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a logic in swift where I'm reading the number of steps the user has walked using `CMPedometer`

`CMPedometer` takes some time to update the result like with a delay of 1-2 seconds in which let's say the user has taken 5 steps it's going to return the value 5.

Now what I want to do is that on every 100 steps taken I want to update user scores. The problem is let's say the user was on step 199 and they opened the app and walked 5 steps the number I'm going to get in return from `CMPedometer` will be 204 which when I put in the if condition `204 % 100 == 0` will not be true and hence I cannot update the score.

```
if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {

   self.pedoMeter.startUpdates(from: Date()) { (data, error) in 
      let stepCount = data.numberOfSteps
      if (stepCount.intValue % 100 == 0) {
          //Upddate scores
      }
   }
}
```

So, what should I change in the if condition to make it work? Is this mathematically possible?

Also, I only keep a record of today's steps taken in the app, so if a user is at 199 steps and they close the app and open it again today they'll continue from 199 so I have that number saved.

Comment: Just divide by 100 then you’ll get something line 1.04 so you know they’ve done 100 once. As their steps increase you’ll get 2.something, 3.something, etc

Comment: @loremipsum If the user closes the app and opens it after some time and I've already sent the update score to call it's gonna send it again as 104/100 would be a valid call right? I want to avoid this that is why I was going with explicit values.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep an int value of `registeredSteps` and increase it whenever the score goes over 100. Once I update the score I increase the value of `registeredSteps`.

```
var registeredSteps = 0

...

if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {
   self.pedoMeter.startUpdates(from: Date()) { [weak self] (data, error) in 
      self?.trackSteps(data.numberOfSteps.intValue)
   }
}

...


func trackSteps(_ steps: Int) {
   let unregisteredSteps = steps - registeredSteps
   if unregisteredSteps > 100 {
      // update scores
      registeredSteps += 100
   }
}
```